# Want to derive an array from Array of Dictionaries in pyspark efficiently

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
   +----------+----------+---------------------+
   | Index    |           flagArray            |
   +----------+----------+---------------------+
   |    1     | [{start :1 , end :2, flag :A}, | 
   |          | {start :3 , end :5, flag :A}]  |
   +----------+--------------------------------+
   |    2     | [{start :1 , end :5, flag :A}] |
   +--------- +----------+---------------------+
```

```
     root
      |-- index: integer (nullable = true)
      |-- flagArray: array (nullable = true)
      |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
      |    |    |-- flag: string (nullable = true)
      |    |    |-- start: integer (nullable = true)
      |    |    |-- end: integer (nullable = true)
```

I want derive a new column Flag based on start, end and flag field of flagArray.

```
   +----------+--------------------------------+------------+
   | Index    |           flagArray            |    flag2   |
   +----------+--------------------------------+------------+
   |    1     | [{start :1 , end :2, flag :A}, | [A,A,S,S,S]|
   |          | {start :3 , end :5, flag :A}]  |            |
   +----------+--------------------------------+------------+ 
   |    2     | [{start :1 , end :5, flag :A}] | [A,A,A,A,A]|
   +--------- +--------------------------------+------------+
```

I have a working code but I wanted to do it in a more efficient way as i will have millions of rows and my will have 300 array elements in Flag column:

```
     @udf(ArrayType(StringType()))
     def set_flag(startIndex,endIndex, flag):
         arraylength = len(startIndex)
         row = []
         for i in range(0,arraylength):
             start = int(startIndex[i])
             end = int(endIndex[i]) + 1
            derFlag = flag[i]
            for i in range(start,endIndex+1):
                row.append(derFlag)
         return row
     df = df.select("*","flagArray.start","flagArray.end","flagArray.flag")
     df = df.withColumn("flag2",set_flag(df.start,df.end,df.flag)).drop("start","end","flag")
```

Comment: Where do `df.start,df.end,df.flag` come from?

Comment: sorry about that, missed a line of code. updated the question. thanks

Comment: in index 1 second flag field is S however in flagarray it is A? so if there is 2 As does the second become S?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, it is completely based on my start and end field of flagArray. I will check what is my flag corresponding to every dictionary in flagArray and keep appending to my output field array.
For index 1 dictionary 1 my start is 1, end is 2, flag is A, and dictionary 2 start is 3, end is 5, flag is S so my output array is [A,A,S,S,S].
For index 2 i have only 1 dictionary where start is 1 and end is 2 and flag is A so my output array is [A,A,A,A,A]

Comment: @Saikat understood, could you post the .printSchema() of your sample dataframe.

Comment: if your spark version is 2.4+ and the column `flagArray` is an array of structs, then you can try this: `df.selectExpr("*", "flatten(transform(flagArray, x -> array_repeat(x.flag, x.end-x.start+1))) as flag2").show()`

Comment: @jxc awesome solution. your solutions always inspire me to learn more and get better. thank you.

Comment: I have updated the post with schema above

Comment: @jxc awsome solution. Thanks a lot =D